# UITextview edit mode in swift

Tags: swift, uitextview

I would like to edit some text in UITextview but whenever keyboard comes, it clear the previous text . I want to previous text on keyboard open as well.

Any one has idea how to do it in swift 3.0?

I am setting the string of UITextView in viewdidload

```
treatment.text = patient?.patientTreatment;
   func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
{
    if textView.text != ""
    {
        textView.text = patient?.patientTreatment
    }
}
```

I observed 1 thing here, My text is disappear once keyboard opens and comes back once keyboard closes.

Comment: you want same as placeholder text ?

Comment: pls more details, share your code

Comment: You are talking about `UITextView` right? Or it's `UITextField`?

Comment: delete everything inside your `func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)` and test once.

Comment: Yes I did that and I have deleted the treatment.becomeFirstResponder() also, It is not taking the focus automatically and not clearing the text.

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to check the condition whether the string present inside the UITextView your PlaceHolder or not

you can use the following

```
  func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
  {
        if textView.text == "YOUR_PLACEHOLDER"  {
          textView.text = ""
        } else if textView.text == ""  {
          textView.text = "YOUR_PLACEHOLDER"
        }
  }
```

Comment: He doesn't want to clear the `textView`. Read the question carefully.

Comment: if we use the text as placeholder means we can clear that otherwise that will  not.Check the above code once you will got the result

Comment: I am using UITextView. I want to 2 thigns here. 1. Adding the placeholder if string is empty. 2. Placing the text if string is not empty. Right now string is clear automatically once keyboard opens.

Comment: @GaneshManickam : I know this will solve the problem of placeholder. My problem is , I have a UITextview in which I set a string in starting. once I click on the uitexview for editing anything, it is clearing my data , I want my previous data to be there while editing it.

Comment: check the value present in `patient?.patientTreatment` or not. I think that will be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here it's an example.

Inside your `viewDidLoad` add this:

```
yourTextView.text = ""
```

And use this delegate method as it is:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
    // your textView is Empty, set your Placeholder
        textView.text = "Placeholder"    // Use your desired String here
    } else {
    // your textView contains some texts, change it according to your needs
        textView.text = "My Text"        // Use your desired String here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

        if textView.text.isEmpty{
            textView.text = "Enter description here..."
            textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }else{

              textView.text = "My description"
          } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

set placeholder in UITextView

```
extension EditProfileVC:UITextViewDelegate{

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
            textView.text = nil
            textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text.isEmpty {
            textView.text = "Placeholder"
            textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }
}
```